# Source files version for vNext build

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

In the XAML build definition I have the possibility to specify the version (latest, by label, by changeset, by date) of the source files that I want to be used by the definition.

How can I get the same behavior in the vNext builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set it as part of the build definition. Only as you Queue the build by the looks of it.

Here's where you can set it when you Queue a build.

[image: Queue Build]

I'd guess that not many people save a build definition with a specific Changeset ID. You'd build the code once, and then retain the build indefinitely if you wanted to keep it. I can't imagine needed more than one build of a particular change. For that reason it probably didn't make it high enough up their backlog to be shipped. If you really want this feature, you'll have to post on the VS User Voice.

Comment: 99% of the time we build the latest version and we label automatically the but from time to time we'd like to build based on a previous build to see exactly what was delivered to clients.

Comment: In that case, why not store the build artifacts (your deliverables)? Not sure why you wouldn't already be doing that on some data store or CD/DVD, etc. As build tools get upgraded and system environments change via updates/patches, it's probably not safe to trust that building the same label/changeset some arbitrary time in the future will produce the same binary output that was delivered.